# Internal monomorphism in the category of functors

Tags: category-theory, monads

The codensity monad can be seen as a sort of endomorphism monoid.

The internal hom or residual with respect to functor composition as the monoid being basically kan extension.

In Set

$$(G/F)(A) = \forall B, (A \rightarrow F(B)) \rightarrow G(B) $$

This leads to the codensity monad.

I was wondering about what if we required a monomorphism?

I'm not sure how to make this precise but I have a feeling you'd want a condition on monadic bind like

$$ x \mathbin{>>=} f = x \mathbin{>>=} g \rightarrow f = g $$

The codensity monad is a little like the continuation monad and I have a feeling monomorphisms ought to correspond to some sort of scoped or possibly one shot continuation.

I suppose if "codensity monos" are interesting one would for completeness also want to look at codensity epimorphisms and automorphisms.

Comment: It would be helpful to make more precise what do you mean by monomorphism.

Comment: @fosco What an "internal monomorphism" ought to be is the crux of the problem I guess.

Comment: Well, there are other problems: in what sense $f,g,x$ are "elements" of the codensity monad, regarded as an endomorphism monoid? Also, being monic is a property that you can state for morphisms that are not endomorphism: is there a reason why you're interested in restricting to endomaps instead? Also, one can speculate there is a meaning behind the "bind" that says $x$ is "monic" if $f\mapsto x \, \gg\kern-.2em= \, \_$ is injective. Have you checked what is the type of "x bind blank" and whether it makes sense to have this intuition?

Comment: @fosco I guess it's probably reasonable to think about the "indexed codensity monad" as well (so a category internal to the category of endofunctors with composition as the monoid). Just the traditional codensity monad is the usual use. I'm not really sure how to state being a mono in terms of join which is more directly the composition operation.

Comment: To define a category internal to an ambient category you need finite limits in the ambient; perhaps you're thinking about the fact that a category is a monad in a bicategory of spans? "Being a mono" is indeed quite hairy to define just in these terms (I'd have to think what it means to be an internal mono, though), because you somehow need "points"... I can expand on this, but it will not be a very clever remark

Comment: @fosco Ah you're right I should have said category *enriched* over the category of endofunctors. No worries  I can't figure out what an internal mono ought to be either. I just hope the question of "what should a mono in categories enriched over endofunctors mean" makes sense to someone else.

Comment: I added an answer on enriched monomorphisms, but it went very far from codensity and Kan extensions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me jot down what -most likely- you have in mind then (re your last comment).

The category $V=[A,A]$ of endofunctors of a category $A$ is strict monoidal with respect to functor composition. The tensor unit is the identity, and all coherence isomorphisms are identities.

> What is a category enriched over $V$?

It's a set $C_0$ of objects, plus

- a function $C_0\times C_0\to V$ sending each pair $x,y : C_0$ to an endofunctor $F_{xy} : A \to A$,
- a morphism in $V$ (so, a natural transformation) $u_x : 1_A \Rightarrow F_{xx}$ for every $x : C_0$, and
- a morphism in $V$ (so, a natural transformation)

$$c_{xyz} : F_{xy}\circ F_{yz} \Rightarrow F_{xz}$$

for every $x,y,z : C_0$, such that the composition is associative and $u_x$ serves as unit; writing down a "element-wise" formula for associativity and unitality would be deceiving, because the hom-objects in a $V$-category are functors, not "sets with elements and additional structure".

But you can get some intuition over this definition, if you observe that every $F_{xx}$ is a monad: $u_x$ is its unit, and the multiplication $c_{xxx}=c_x=F_{xx}\circ F_{xx}\Rightarrow F_{xx}$ is the multiplication. So,

> a monad on $A$ is just a one-object $[A,A]$-category.

(side remark: this point of view has been adopted to elegantly describe finitary monads as one-object $W$-categories, where $W$ is the category of finitary endofunctors of $\sf Set$; see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2963))

What about the multiobject version? Well, as far as I can see the multi-object version of a $[A,A]$-category has been studied, but doesn't have a name: *monadoid* is terrible; maybe *paramonad*, drawing from [this paper](https://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf)?

> And what about monomorphisms?

Well, we have a general notion of monomorphism in a $V$-category (for every base of enrichment): see 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0315.pdf)

From each $V$-category $\underline C$ you can extract an ordinary category $C$, with the same objects $C_0$ and where $\hom(x,y) := V(I,\underline{C}(x,y))$ ($I$ the monoidal unit, $\underline{C}(x,y) : V$ the hom-object of $\underline{C}$).

A morphism $m : x\to y$ in the underlying category (so a morphism $m : I\to \underline C(x,y)$ in $V$) now is a $V$-monomorphism when the morphism $C(a,m) : C(a,x)\to C(a,y)$ is a monomorphism in $V$. The definition of $C$ and of the functor $C(a,-)$ now say that $m$ is a monomorphism when

$$ V(I,[a,x]) \xrightarrow{V(I,[a,x]\otimes m)} V(I, [a,x]\otimes[x,y]) \xrightarrow{V(I,c)} V(I, [a,y]) $$

is a monomorphism in $V$.

> What does this notion reduce to when $V=[A,A]$?

I am afraid it's going to be a mouthful and not particularly enlightening: the morphisms in the underlying category of a $[A,A]$-category are natural transformations of type $1_A \Rightarrow F_{xy}$; if (building a weird enough $[A,A]$-category where the endofunctor $F_{xy} :A \to A$ can't be pointed for some $x,y : C_0$) there are no such transformations, the hom-set in question is empty. Stupid problems like this besides, though, the notion isn't very enlightening even in case it's not vacuously true: you have a map

$$ [A,A](1_A,F_{ax}) \to [A,A](1_A, F_{ax}\circ F_{xy}) \to [A,A](1_A, F_{ay}) $$ and you want it to be a monomorphism (of sets!)

Comment: Thank you. This answer is a bit learned for me to disentangling ATM but definitely seems right. IIRC a multi object monad is one concept of an indexed monad.

Comment: I guess it makes sense you get a "monic codensity monoid/category" not monad using enriched category theory. So I still don't really understand what you wrote but aren't those natural transformations just natural Kleisli arrows? I tried fooling around a bit with monos in the Kliesli category in Coq https://gist.github.com/mstewartgallus/cd7b2f6912687d87ceed2ca4b81e0600 . I think maybe something to do with EM algebras might be worth exploring I guess. Anyway thanks.

Comment: The multi-object notion of monads are special kinds of [polyad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyad).